# Flutter WorkManager giving does not implement abstract member public abstract fun error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-workmanager

I m a bit new to flutter and, I am trying to get and post currentLocation to backend service on flutter from background but I can't manage to run the program with WorkManager, it gives this error;

e: /Users/fmss/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/workmanager-0.4.1/android/src/main/kotlin/be/tramckrijte/workmanager/BackgroundWorker.kt: (132, 21): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun error(p0: String, p1: String?, p2: Any?): Unit defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
e: /Users/fmss/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/workmanager-0.4.1/android/src/main/kotlin/be/tramckrijte/workmanager/BackgroundWorker.kt: (137, 25): 'error' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':workmanager:compileDebugKotlin'.

And this is my main.dart;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:modernlogintute/pages/current_location_page.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';
import 'pages/login_page.dart';


void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {

    //print("bakalım sürekli arkada çalışıyor mu");
    LoginPage loginPage=LoginPage();
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    loginPage.postLastLocation(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    print('Executing task');
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
    print('Task executed: ' + taskName);
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);
  runApp(const MyApp());

}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState()=>MyAppState();
  const MyApp({super.key});
}
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupWorkManager();
  }
  void setupWorkManager() async {
    Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask("task1","task",
        frequency: const Duration(seconds: 15),
        existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.append
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show lines 132 and 137 of `BackgroundWorker.kt`?